# Make curved edge using css

Tags: html, css, colors

I am trying to make curved edge using css instead of using background image.

[image]

White div is on top of grey one. Currently white curve is achieved using a bg image. Please help on how to achieve above mentioned design with out a background image? So that I can change the color of the white div dynamically.

Comment: [This](https://css-tricks.com/scooped-corners-in-2018/) is helps. Can you include your code . the last code add to question. more than asking question with image. create a [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You should investigate using an SVG for this- it would be easy to create the path for this shape.

Comment: I don't think that you can realize 1:1 this shape without using a SVG or background image. The closest solution whould be to use ````clip-path```` property. 

[clip-path - CSS | MDN][1]


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: I have done it using SVG, sass and mixins. Thanks for all support here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it using SVG format. First, you can make that shape with Figma or Adobe Illustrator or whatever you like. You import that image in SVG format to the code. In that format, there's a line of code that you can edit to manipulate the color of that shape. (SVG is an image that imported as a code). I hope this helpful.

Comment: Whilst I a agree - and posted a comment to this effect - this answer would be best as a comment. An answer should provide either some code or a solution to the problem (for example if you had actually included the SVG code) - but when the answer is a suggestion or a direction to investigate - it is best as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .header {
      border-top: 20px solid blue;
      height:100px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .header:before,
    .header:after {
      content: "";
      vertical-align:top;
      display: inline-block;
      transform-origin: top right;
      transform: skew(-40deg);
    }
    
    .header:before {
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%;
      border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
      background: blue;
    }
    
    .header:after {
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      margin-left:-1px;
      background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom right, transparent 68%, blue 73%);
    }
    
    
    /*to illustrate different values of skew*/
    .header:before,
    .header:after {
      animation:change 2s linear infinite alternate;
    }
    
    @keyframes change{
      from{transform: skew(0deg);}
      top{transform: skew(-40deg);}
    }

#Use 
<div class="header"></div>
```